# Program has stopped working , only in "Release" Configuration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Please when i choose "Release" in configuration manager and try to open my program exe and work in it , A message box with "myprogram has stopped working .." , This happens just when release mode is choosen but debug mode, the program runs fine and no problems !

my program contains datasets and connections and more , all are about working with database access

Note: that message box dosen't appear when start my program , it appears after start and when open and close a certain forms

i cant put my code , it is very big about 1000 lines but i'am using this simple code to show a certain form :

```
 Dim o As New commandsSearch
    o.ShowDialog()
    o.Dispose()
```

i think it is a memory problem , maybe?

please give me your solutions :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen when you make initialization calls (using `new`) in declarations. If there is an error during initialization, the messages can be generic at best. Try temporarily commenting out classes, etc., that are created before the initial form has been loaded, a few at a time, until you narrow it down (or eliminate it as a possibility).